# ¿Cómo puedo pasar el valor de una variable de bash a c?

Tags: c, bash, diálogo

Intento usar la función "dialog" de bash para hacer un menú en c, aquí mi código.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define SHELLSCRIPT "fundialog=${fundialog=dialog}; opcion=`$fundialog --stdout --title 'Opcion' --yesno 'Comes pan?' 0 0`;echo $?"
int main(){
    int opcion = system(SHELLSCRIPT);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Y por qué no hacer dicho menú en C directamente? Hay alguna ventaja en específico?

Comment: No, pero solo quería aprender a usarlo

Comment: Entonces te gustara leer [esto](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3416638/set-environment-variables-in-c).